# Ionic2 and AWS Integration

Tags: amazon-web-services, ionic2, aws-sdk

Does anyone have any examples or could possibly point me in the right direction on how to integrate aws-sdk within Ionic 2?

I tried running the code below:

**npm install aws-sdk --save 

typings install dt~aws-sdk --save --global**

But now when I try to build or run the app I get:

*TypeScript error: typings/globals/aws-sdk/index.d.ts(1575,24): Error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Buffer'.*

I'm fairly new to Ionic2 so how would I go about importing this sdk to use?

Thanks in advance

SDK Link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk 
Ionic 2: http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/

Comment: stuck at the same point ... Any clue so far?

Comment: I have been searching high and low for an answer and don't have one yet,   I think i'm going to attempt to write my own integration, need to learn a little more about typescript to debug this error.

Will post here if I find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

To anyone else stuck trying to integrate AWS into ionic2 then please follow this link.

https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cognito-angular2-quickstart/issues/8

Vladimir Budilov at AWS was kind enough to share his repository.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above solutions worked for me, For my case the following worked:

In your angular or ionic project run:

```
npm install aws-sdk --save
```

Before you can begin using these TypeScript definitions with your project, you need to make sure your project meets a few of these requirements:

```
npm install --save-dev @types/node
```